# create javascript file for use on different servers

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, server

I want to create a JS file that others can include on their websites so they can reference the functions which access my db using an api similar to the facebook like button which shows the total liked and who of your friends like the page.  What I've been doing as part of my testing is the following:
JS file

```
function getItemRating(id){
    var result = "";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://siteurl.com/api/rating.php",
        data: {i : id},
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function(data) { // callback for successful completion
          result = data;
        },
        error: function() { // callback if there's an error
          result = 'error';
        }
      });
    return result;
}
```

Reference file includes:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

and on the other server I've tried a few ways including:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="www.siteurl.com/api/rating-file.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var result = getItemRating(1);
    console.log(result);


});
</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

But currently I'm getting the error in console:

VM133:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://siteurl.com/api/rating.php' from origin 'http://otherurl.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

siteurl.com = my server where the js file (with function) is located
otherurl.com = different server that the html including the js is located

Comment: You've told us what you want, and shown us some code, but you haven't told us what the problem is.

Comment: `async: false` — This is deprecated.

Comment: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` — This makes no sense. You are making a GET request. There is no content to describe the type of.

Comment: is this part of a browser extension? Most of the [search results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Unchecked+runtime.lastError%3A+Could+not+establish+connection.+Receiving+end+does+not+exist.&oq=Unchecked+runtime.lastError%3A+Could+not+establish+connection.+Receiving+end+does+not+exist.&aqs=chrome..69i57.150j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) relating to this online appear to be based in that scenario.

Comment: @Liam — `siteurl` is under the control of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that the problem is with the response to the preflight request, but you shouldn't be triggering one in the first place.

Remove:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

because:

- It is a lie. You aren't POSTing JSON in your GET request.
- Setting the content-type to that value triggers a preflight request.

Comment: sorry, just realised I hadn't updated that in the description.  corrected now

Comment: @AlanDoolan — It's still a lie because you are posting form encoded data, not JSON.

Comment: @AlanDoolan — That's very odd. If you remove that there should be nothing to trigger a preflight. Are you sure the error hasn't changed at all? Do you have an `ajaxSetup` call that you didn't include in the question?